# все txt файлы на кириллице превратились в "кракозябру"

Tags: кириллица

Все кириллические блокнотовские файлы на моем компьютере (Windows 10) превратились в кракозябру. Можно ли что-то с этим сделать? Я могу прочитать их с помощью онлайн-декодера, но это не очень удобно, т.к. файлов много... Заранее признательна за ваши ответы.

Comment: вы видите что-то вроде "агббЄЁ© вҐЄбв"?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B/49b45334-e9c5-41f2-be45-482cbcbea928?auth=1

Comment: Нет, вижу вот такое: âîçìîæíî

Comment: Visman, спасибо огромное, ваша ссылка мне помогла решить проблему! :)

Comment: @ElizavetaLevina если думаете что нашли решение, опубликуйте его как свой ответ — [это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs там костыль с поменой nls файла. На самом деле проблема топикастера решается выставлением языка для не-unicode приложений в настройках системы

Comment: @PashaPash: если решение здесь опубликовано, то здесь можно за него и проголосовать и комментарий оставить и опубликовать лучшую альтернативу.

Answer (score 3):

1. Откройте Control Panel (Desktop App)
2. Clock, Language, and Region.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Region.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Закладка Administrative
5. Language for non-Unicode programs, поменяйте на Руссский
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Перезагрузитесь

Обычно для этой же проблемы гуглится хак с подменой nls файла (то, что вам посоветовали в комментариях к вопросу) . Но подмена nls - это просто костыль, т. к.  вместо смены настройки она поменяет системный файл, за выбор которого эта настройка отвечает.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш совет! Воспользовалась приведенной выше ссылкой, мне помогло.